# What API or framework should i use to implement this messaging system in Java?

Tags: java, api, frameworks, jms, messaging

I am building a messaging system where i have an application which sends a message to several recipients, these recipients will be invoked by the sending application with the message rather than ask the sending application of any new messages. The recipients must also handle whatever message they get in order(perhaps using some queue) and these messages are not specific to any recipient.

I am looking into various frameworks and APIs such as JMS to implement this but are there any other ways that would be quicker and simpler way of implementing this type of system? The solution also needs to be very scalable as it will be dealing with many recipients and perhaps many sending applications.

Thanks.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. As a result, I've voted to close.

Comment: I agree with @Duncan Jones. As of my opinion, RabbitMQ is very easy to use and seems to fit. If you have specific requirements and criteria to measure, we could maybe answer this :)

Comment: @C4stor well i am looking into JMS so i guess anything simpler and quicker than that would be the answer, and thanks will look into RabbitMQ.

Comment: Never used JMS, so can't really compare. I used a lot RabbitMQ mainly cause it's cross languages, and I do both java and c# applications. Also, in my experience, it scales very well. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMS, with a publish and subscribe message model seems a good fit for this.

A number of free messaging technologies exist ( RabbitMQ seems to be popular but I have never used it ).

Answer (score 1):

Try akka(http://akka.io/)

Basically its framework for building concurrent application but it has nice messaging system at its core.